# Фильтр по параметрам при работе с бд?(Java)

Tags: java, веб-программирование, spring

Как реализовать удобный фильтр по параметрам при работе с бд? Вот сразу вспоминаются интернет магазины(там как раз по множеству входящих параметров достаются объекты). Есть набор Entity у которых разные свойства, которые как раз и являются критериями для выдергивания Entity из бд. Эти параметры бывают разными и float и String, int. Как так извернуться чтобы под каждую сущность не писать свой репозиторий для обработки запросов?

Хотелось бы работать со Spring Data Jpa, но это не обязательно... Есть идея передавать одним параметром массив, но так как типы разные и в Jpa не передать массив то это не вариант. Можно написать один большой репозиторий, но тоже не вариант, так как методов может быть за 20 и все описывать в одном месте не комильфо. Можно заменить все типы на String, но это совсем бред. Что можете подсказать?

Comment: У каждой Entity должен быть свой репозиторий. Фильтр по параметрам удобнее будет реализовать используя Spring Data

Comment: @bsuart это догадка или опыт? на 20 ентити, 20 репозиториев?

Comment: @cori, да именно так.

Comment: Сделать единый интерфейс с дефолтными методами определения сущностей (типов, параметров... - что Вам конкретно нужно будет), и использовать Stream Api для фильтрации результата

Comment: @cori, это опыт. Да именно так на 20 entity 20 repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Удобный фильтр по параметрам при работе с бд.
>   Хотелось бы работать со Spring Data Jpa

Это не совсем к Spring Data вопрос. Всё-таки то, что вы описываете ("как в интернет-магазине, по множеству параметров") не является DAO (или Repository) в том варианте, в котором это трактует Spring Data. В вашем случае - это некий обобщенный фильтр, и решение стоит искать ближе к БД. Например, я подобную задачу успешно реализовал с использованием фреймворка Hibernate и его Criteria API.